# efficiently remove substring that may not contain a specific word -

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, performance, regex-lookarounds

I try to map some aweful invalid html-code with php to a xml-structure I need later on. This works quite well, but there is always some part that I just can't handle. So the decission is, do just remove that code so that the xml stays valid. This is how it might look like.

```
<body>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>def</item>
    unparsable rest
</body>
```

So the goal is, to find a solution (probably regex but I'm open to any solution) to just remove the "unparsable rest".

I tried using preg_replace with this regex

```
/<\/item>(((?!item).)*)\s*<\/body>/iU
```

And it worked pretty well, matching exactly the part I wanted to have in $1, all the stuff between the last  and , but as the xmls are quite large, the calculation just crashes after a couple of milliseconds. I know that regex are not so good doing the negative-lookahead-stuff, but I didn't think it was that bad.

So there needs to be a more efficient solution. Unfortunately I can't use strrpos as there are much more  tags after the

Comment: Over-simplifying, you can check for `</tag>.*?<` Basically anything malformed between the closing tag of an element and the next (valid) opening tag. Though this kind of interrogation should be done via a parser not brute-forcing it with patterns. (Not saying you're married to patterns, but a parser would be a better bet).

Comment: but a parser might not parse invalid stuff, that's exactly my problem :)

Comment: and `</item>.*?<` will match the first closing item, not the last one as it doesn't know, that there shouldn't be another item in the text i want to have

Comment: I'm not saying anything out-of-box, I'm saying you're better off writing a parser. You mentioned this is the result of a conversion previously. The previous conversion sounds like it needs to be worked on, not the band aid for where it failed.

Comment: Well if you tell me a HTML-Parser that can deal with things like `<p><b>text</p></b>` (and this is one of the nice mistakes) I would take it :) But loadHtml() has no chance at all. I am actually writing a lot of parsing rules that igonre mistakes, but at some point it would just take 20 hours for one page. So the decission is to just remove the rest.

Comment: Have you tried the ones found on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) to see which gets you closest? (This is assuming the refactoring the original PHP code that's causing the malformed code isn't an option).

Comment: the malformed html is an export of a website being edited by people with no idea what they are doing that should be moved to another cms. so no, i can't change anything on the html or the things that are producing it :) I'll take a look at all those different parsers. But still, it's not a solution for Stuff it just can't handle (what my actual question was)

Comment: Please check my answer, it is more of academic interest, I suppose.

Comment: Did any of the anwers work for you?

Comment: The problem is over 8 years old... The project is finished since pretty much 7.5 years. I didn't need it anymore and am not even working in the same company anymore to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) in your regex pattern. It is slow by its nature, see the "Performance Issue" section in the answer I link to.

So, your current regex, that I prefer to write without `U` and with `s` modifier as `~</item>(((?!item).)*?)\s*?</body>~is`, [matches your input string within 231 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aFMySX/1).

Note there is no much semantic difference in `\s*` and `\s*?` here since there is no other quantified pattern before `</body>`. `\s*`, the greedy pattern, is preferred in such cases.

Let's [unroll](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) the pattern and replace `((?!item).)*?` with `[^i]*(?:i(?!tem)[^i]*)*`. The `~</item>([^i]*(?:i(?!tem)[^i]*)*)\s*</body>~is` [matches your input within 117 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aFMySX/2).

This is still quite a lot for the string. The whitespace after `</item>` can be matched *possessively* with `\s*+` to cut the backtracking access to that part of string. The `~</item>\s*+([^i]*(?:i(?!tem)[^i]*)*)\s*</body>~is` shows an improvement, now [it takes 89 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aFMySX/3) to match the string, and only `unparsable rest` lands in Group 1 value.

Unfortunately, we cannot play with backtracking much here since you want to cut off trailing whitespace from Group 1 value.

If you want to match all between `</item>` and `</body>` that does not contain `<item>` inside, the pattern will look like `~</item>\s*+([^<]*(?:<(?!item>)[^<]*)*)\s*</body>~is`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFMySX/4).

Answer (score 0):

Check each line to start with '<' and end with '>':

```php
$t ='<body>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>def</item>
    unparsable rest
</body>';

// break the string into lines
$filtered = array_filter(explode("\n", $t), function($line) {
    // each line
    $line = trim($line); //ignore white spaces
    return $line[0] == '<' && substr($line, -1) == '>';
});
// rebuild the string
$result = implode("\n", $filtered);
echo $result;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Mt5eG