# Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, eclipse

```
<table((?!</table>).)*</table>
```

matches all my table tags. However,

```
<table(.(?!</table>))*</table>
```

does not.  The second one seems to make sense if I try to write out the expression in words, but I can't make sense of the first.

What is the difference ?

For reference, I got the term "Tempered Greedy Token" from here: *[Tempered Greedy Token Solution](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)*

Comment: As an aside, note that this "tempered" way is particularly inefficient.

Comment: Then .. _he_ made it up. In fact, this is not standard  jargon in regex land. And if I were to take a poll, am betting %99 of regex guru's would laugh at it.

Comment: Well, the author of that website seems pretty guru to me.  Plus, I think it's helpful to have names for patterns - regex or otherwise.  I would just let the gurus laugh.  Btw, is there a more standard name for this pattern?

Comment: Yeah. I would call it the _Record Seperator Construct_ because that's it's only use. It's the last resort, most _ineficient_  way to match anything. Same goes for using an assertion at the beginning of a regex (this must never be done!!).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll ask you the same question you asked me: Did you make `Record Seperator Construct` up?  I doubt that is any more standard than `Tempered Greedy Token`.  In fact, google gives me zero hits for that phrase.

Comment: Well buddy, you didn't ask me what `Record $eperator Construct` is: `Regex1:   (?s)(?=(.+?)(helloWorld|$))\1\2 Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 ) Matches found per iteration:   4 Elapsed Time:    0.91 s,   906.47 ms,   906468 µs` Now compare that with `Temered Greedy Token` :  `Regex2:   (?s)(?:(?!helloWorld).)+(?:helloWorld|$) Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 ) Matches found per iteration:   4 Elapsed Time:    1.74 s,   1744.49 ms,   1744490 µs` Which one shows up on google ?

Comment: Here's another one `Record $eperator Construct:   (?s)<table(?=(.*?)(</table>))\1\2 Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000  ) Matches found per iteration:   3 Elapsed Time:    0.58 s,   581.96 ms,   581957 µs` versus `Temered Greedy Token:   (?s)<table(?:(?!</table>).)*</table> Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 ) Matches found per iteration:   3 Elapsed Time:    1.63 s,   1627.50 ms,   1627500 µs` Do you really think that guy is a guru when he espouses _crud_ and actually makes up a _faux_ name for it ?...

Comment: It seems like you are taking issue with two separate things.  One, that the expression is inefficient, and two, that the author of rexegg made up a term for it.  For the first issue, I feel it necessary to point out that the efficiency of the pattern was never a part of the original question, though I do thank you for taking the time to post those benchmarks!  For you second issue, you're going to have to ask the author why he chose that term.  I can't answer that one!  It looks like he has a comments section at the bottom of this page though.  You could try that.

Comment: @jrahhali - The question is labeled `Temper Greedy Token` of which you post a link to a guy's website who made this phrase up and is promoting a Regex Consulting Service. This phrase cannot be branded to a sequence of regex constructs, period! Any by you _pushing_ it as if it is something relavent to something significant, undermines the fact that regex is a flowing language that can only be defined by individual constructs in _techniques_ that can't be defined. Even _unrolled loop_, a common and more meningfull phrase, is irrelavent.

Comment: So, I wouldn't take this form as some _gold standard_ since it comes in many shapes `<table(.(?!(?<!<)/table>))*</table>` _after_. What's real here is assertions, not some branded technique. And, should you ever be actually looking for something specific, it should never be checked with a _leading_ assertion. This put's a 2x performance hit right out of the gate.

Comment: Well, you're definitely entitled to your opinion, and thanks for sharing it! I personally see value in naming constructs, so disagree with you on that point.  Further, I didn't intend to *push* anything as some *gold standard*. It was just an straight-forward, innocent question. But even if I intended to, I don't see a problem with that. I'm sorry if that ruffles some feathers. I suggest you create an answer with all the points you've listed. That would probably be the most helpful thing to do here, while at the same time, reign in this dialog from becoming more off topic. What do you think?

Comment: @jrahhali - Ah, yeah.. I see it time to time. New to regex people, grasping at coined phrases as if trying to memorize some way they have seen something done. It's human nature to do that. I try to subtly enlighten, but sometimes it doesn't work. Here is a _fact_ for you - regex is an _applied_ science, it's not theoretical. It changes shape and form _every_ time. There is _no_ technique. You are _alone_ with a variety of singular constructs and an idea of what you want to create. You can only get better by practice, and a lot of it. Memorizing phrases won't help at all, good luck to you!

Comment: Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## What is a Tempered Greedy Token?

The rexegg.com [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) reference is quite concise:

> In `(?:(?!{END}).)*`, the `*` quantifier applies to a dot, but it is now a *tempered* dot. The negative lookahead `(?!{END})` asserts that what follows the current position is not the string `{END}`. Therefore, the dot can never match the opening brace of `{END}`, guaranteeing that we won't jump over the `{END}` delimiter.

That is it: a ***tempered greedy token* is a kind of a *negated character class* for a character *sequence*** (cf. [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for a *single character*).

**NOTE**: The *difference between a tempered greedy token and a negated character class* is that the former does not really match the text other than the sequence itself, but a *single character* that does not start that sequence. I.e. [`(?:(?!abc|xyz).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/C0BJAJ/1) won't match `def` in `defabc`, but will match `def` *and* `bc`, because `a` starts the forbidden `abc` sequence, and `bc` does not.

It consists of:

- `(?:...)*` - a quantified non-capturing group (it may be a capturing group, but it makes no sense to capture each individual character) (a `*` can be `+`, it depends on whether an empty string match is expected)
- `(?!...)` - a negative lookahead that actually imposes a restriction on the value to the right of the current location
- `.` - (or any (usually single) character) a consuming pattern.

However, we can always further temper the token by using alternations in the negative lookahead (e.g. `(?!{(?:END|START|MID)})`) or by replacing the all-matching dot with a negated character class (e.g. `(?:(?!START|END|MID)[^<>])` when trying to match text only inside tags).

## Consuming part placement

Note there is no mentioning of a construction where a consuming part (the dot in the original tempered greedy token) is placed *before* the lookahead. Avinash's answer is explaining that part clearly: `(.(?!</table>))*` first matches any character (but a newline without a DOTALL modifier) and then checks if it is not followed with `</table>` resulting in a failure to match `e` in [`<table>table</table>`](https://regex101.com/r/yX9bJ1/1). **The consuming part (the `.`)* ***must*** **be placed after the tempering lookahead**.

## When should we use a tempered greedy token?

Rexegg.com gives an idea:

- When we want to match a block of text between Delimiter 1 and Delimiter 2 with no Substring 3 in-between (e.g. `{START}(?:(?!{(?:MID|RESTART)}).)*?{END}`
- When we want to match a block of text containing a specific pattern inside *without overflowing* subsequent blocks (e.g. instead of lazy dot matching as in [`<table>.*?chair.*?</table>`](https://regex101.com/r/yX9bJ1/2), we'd use something like [`<table>(?:(?!chair|</?table>).)*chair(?:(?!<table>).)*</table>`](https://regex101.com/r/yX9bJ1/3)).
- When we want to match the shortest window possible between 2 strings. Lazy matching won't help when you need to get `abc 2 xyz` from `abc 1 abc 2 xyz` (see [`abc.*?xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/xU4gM0/2) and [`abc(?:(?!abc).)*?xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/xU4gM0/4)).

## Performance Issue

Tempered greedy token is resource-consuming as a lookahead check is performed after each character matched with the consuming pattern. [Unrolling the loop technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) can significantly increase tempered greedy token performance.

Say, we want to match `abc 2 xyz` in *abc 1 **abc 2 xyz** 3 xyz*. Instead of checking each character between `abc` and `xyz` with [`abc(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/xU4gM0/6), we can skip all characters that are not `a` or `x` with `[^ax]*`, and then match all `a` that are not followed with `bc` (with `a(?!bc)`) and all `x` that are not followed with `yz` (with `x(?!yz)`): [`abc[^ax]*(?:a(?!bc)[^ax]*|x(?!yz)[^ax]*)*xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/xU4gM0/5).

Comment: After this post being resureccted in the comments section, I've decided to accept your very fleshed-out answer instead.  Thank you for taking the time to put this together.

Answer (score 10):

`((?!</table>).)*` would check for that particular character going to be matched must not be a starting character in the string `</table>`. If yes, then it only matches that particular character. `*` repeats the same zero or more times.

`(.(?!</table>))*` matches any character only if it's not followed by `</table>`, zero or more times. So this would match all the characters inside the table tag except the last character, since the last character is followed by `</table>`. And the following pattern `</table>` asserts that there must be a closing table tag at the end of the match. This makes the match to fail.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/rE9iJ0/4).

Comment: I'm still struggling with understanding the first paragraph.  Good news is that I understand your explanation about why (.(?!</table>))* fails. EDIT: Ohhh, ok, i think i understand now!

Answer (score 6):

A *tempered greedy token* really just means:

> "match, but only up to a point"

How you do it:

> you put the token *you don't want to match* as a negative lookahead
> `(?!notAllowedToMatch)` in front of a dot `.` (match any one
> thing), then you repeat *that whole thing* with a star `*`:
>
> `((?!notAllowedToMatch).)*`

How it works:

> **"look, and eat one"** over and over, moving *one character at time from left to right* through the input string, until the disallowed sequence (or end of string) is seen, at which point the match stops.

[Wiktor's more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088) is nice, but I just thought a simpler explanation was in order.